# Cross Origin Preflight request fails(Chrome)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, cross-domain

I'm trying to send a cross domain POST request with content type json. I configured the server headers to accept the origin, the headers, etc. If I make a GET request, it succeeds, however, if I make a POST request, the Preflight fails.

Here is a screenshot of the network communication: 
http://d.pr/i/JsM

The code:

```
jq.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: dataStr,
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            //processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },...
```

The reason I'm at a loss is because the GET request succeeds The only different between them is that the GET request does not include Access-Control-Request-Headers, etc, headers in the request.

UPDATE: If I change the dataType to "text/plain", it works. What the hell?

Comment: Your server is simply not handling the preflight/OPTIONS request correctly.  It's responding with a 400.  You'll need to fix your server code.

Comment: @RayNicholus: Ah yea, I completely bypassed that. Here's how I fixed it: http://serverfault.com/questions/231766/returning-200-ok-in-apache-on-http-options-requests/231782#231782

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/. Take a look at "CORS from JQuery" section, in the code comment it says:

```
// The 'contentType' property sets the 'Content-Type' header.
// The JQuery default for this property is
// 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', which does not trigger
// a preflight. If you set this value to anything other than
// application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
// you will trigger a preflight request.
contentType: 'text/plain'
```